# Login system using PHP myadmin not working

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I followed a tutorial to create a simple login system using php. I have installed `wampserver` and created the database from phpmyadmin panel. It's not working and I belive it's a problem with the servers. When I created the database the server that appeared there was `mysql wampserver` and in the tutorial was `localhost`. I changed the name of the server in the `config.inc.php` to `localhost`but is still not working. When I click the login button it takes back to the index page of wampserver. I will share my code maybe someone can find the bug because I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

dbConnect.php

```
<?php
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tests");
?>
```

user.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // Put stored session variables into local PHP variable
    $uid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $usname = $_SESSION['username'];
    $result = "Test variables: <br /> Username: ".$usname. "<br /> Id: ".$uid;
} else {
    $result = "You are not logged in yet";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $usname ;?> - Test Site</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo $result;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

first.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

        // Include the databas connection script
    include_once("dbConnect.php");

    $usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    //$usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $usname);
    //$paswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $paswd);



    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE username = '$usname' AND activated = '1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $uid = $row[0];
    $dbUsname = $row[1];
    $dbPassword = $row[2];

    // Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
    if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd == $dbPassword) {
        // Set session 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
        // Now direct to users feed
        header("Location: user.php");
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Oops that username or password combination was incorrect.
        <br /> Please try again.</h2>";
    }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Basic login system</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1>Simple PHP Login</h1>
<form id="form" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clearly formed.  The only thing I can see from what you've stated is that your form action is `index.php` when perhaps it should be `first.php`?

Comment: `index.php` is the starting page from wampserver.

Comment: try removing form action.

Comment: I understand that, but you have `first.php` displayed as the login form and the code that checks your username / password.

Comment: At first I tried without a db connection. I declared 2 variables `usname` and `passwd` and it worked. Now that I try to take those values from the database is not working anymore.

Comment: @RhapX I don't undestand what is it that you are not clear with?

Comment: i think you are getting problem here  
change `$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE username = '$usname' AND activated = '1' LIMIT 1";` 
to 
`$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE username = '".$usname."' and password ='".$paswd."' AND activated = '1' LIMIT 1";`

Comment: @dres By stating in your question "When I click the login button it takes back to the index page of wampserver." you are making it sound like the code is not even hitting your script.  You explain nowhere what your actual problem is other than it redirects you back to index.php.  The list of files and code you show does not include an `index.php` but `first.php` instead.  Thus, it could be a simple naming issue of the action.  However, I agree with Noman as to having an issue with your syntax, but you've never stated that an error was printing.

Comment: Well something is not working ook, because I changed back to the way it was before, without a db connection and the same thing happends. I am redirected to the main page of wamp . The code I changed `$dbUsname = "Peter";
 $dbPassword = "test1";` instead of retrieving those values from database

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injections; "strip_tags" only escapes against XSS and it doesn't fit for MySQL. At worst if you really don't want to use prepared statements you should use "mysqli_real_escape_string" which would use the correct escape sequences for MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What RhapX is trying to explain is that your form action tells the form where to post the data.  Currently, you have

`<form id="form" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

That means once a user hits Submit its going to send them to index.php and will send the $_POST data with them.  But you are saying that first.php is the file that is actually doing all the work, so you need to send the user and $_POST data to first.php instead.  Change it to:

`<form id="form" action="first.php" method="post">`

(Change the action to first.php and just get rid of the enctype -- it might be correct, but it's completely unnecessary and I've seen it cause problems for some.)

Comment: It's the most obvious.  If changing that doesn't fix it I'll spend more time looking at it.

Comment: Nice :)  And I'm sure we've all done it.  Now, go look into hashing your passwords in the database because if you are directly checking whether or not the password that was sent via $_POST matches what is in the database that means that you are storing your password in plaintext, which is no good.   :D